# Automating a context menu using Python when Lock Screen is on

Tags: python, automation, ui-automation, autoit

I have the task to automate a Windows based application using Python. I was able to achieve many of those tasks using the [pyautoit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoIt/0.3) package - but there was one task that requires a context menu to appear on right-clicking in a window. I was not able to detect menu options using AutoIt. So I have used the Send function which sends Keyboard key signals. Using the below code I was able to achieve selecting the menu option I wanted:

```
    autoit.send("{UP}")
    autoit.send("{UP}")
    autoit.send("{UP}")
    autoit.send("{UP}")
    autoit.send("{UP}")
    autoit.send("{UP}")
    autoit.send("{LEFT}")
    autoit.send("{DOWN}")
    autoit.send("{ENTER}")
```

The problem I am facing now is that the code would not work if my computer is locked (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>). Since AutoIt would not recognize that context menu, I am sure it cannot be done using that package. I want to know if there is any package in Python that I could use to achieve this task. I want the code to work even **when the PC is locked**.

Comment: You can just use `autoit.send("{Up 6}{Left}{Down}{Enter}")` instead of calling it multiple times.

Comment: Do you get an ID using RanorexSpy?

Comment: I havent tried that.But as i could see it is not free of cost.We need to purchase it.Actually i am looking at packages which is free of cost.Is there any packages that is a freeware for acheiving this task ?

Comment: You can find a free Version somewhere in a [Forum](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/130371-automate-qt-and-qwidgets/). I downloaded it a while ago and it really helps.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I [know](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/FAQ#Why_doesn.27t_my_script_work_on_a_locked_workstation.3F) you can use the [`Control...(...)`-functions](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlCommand.htm) while being in windows lock screen but you cannot use the [`Send(...)` function](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm).

There is a [`ControlSend(...)`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) though, but you would need a ControlHandle/ID to use it.

Comment: Thank you Samoth..But my problem here is the autoit does not detect the context menu.No id is being shown for that context menu.That is why i am searching is there any other alternative for acheiving that task.Like is there any package in python or autoit to select the context menu options

Comment: @user2078883 then your answer might be not clear enough yet, I tried to answer it as it is. If you appreciate my efforts you might upvote it (as this site is about reputation which is based on voting). You don't need to mark it as answered, if you seek another hint, of course.